# Make result from an Array.map() add into one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

I have an array of strings `['string1', 'string2']` and I want to transform each one of them into (example: `blob:http://something-new`) but i get a result of `(2) [Promise, Promise]`. How to get the resolved value?

**here is the code**

```
const results = id.map(async assetId => {
    const responseIds = await API.assets.getAssetFileById(assetId);
    let asset = responseIds.data.asset;
    const urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    const blobFile = await file_helper.dataUrlToBlob(asset.file);

    return asset.file = await urlCreator.createObjectURL(blobFile);
});

console.log(results) // (2) [Promise, Promise]
```

**Expected output:**

```
console.log(results) // (2) ['blob:http://something-new1', 'blob:http://something-new2']
```

Comment: [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: You should put the promises in `Promise.all()` and once they all resolve then create the array. This is similar to the forEach issue.

Comment: `return X = await Y;` can have some funky behavior. Try doing `let X = await Y; return X;`

Comment: @Abion47 how is it different?

Comment: @zerkms I'm not sure of the exact reason but it's happened to me before where doing it the first way wasn't working where the second way did. It's also encouraged to do it that way by many style guides anyway, so I don't argue.

Comment: @Abion47 https://jsfiddle.net/hr6o09px/ 

Comment: You get `Promise` because an `async` function always returns a promise.

Answer (score 2):

```
Promise.all(results).then(function(urls) {
  console.log(urls);
});
```

You need to wait for all of the promises to resolve, then you can work with them.